# JScrollPane doesn't display the provided component in the constructor

Tags: java, swing

JScrollPane doesn't show what component i put inside it's constructor

```
panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
JButton button = new JButton("button");
panel.add(button);
scroll = new JScrollPane(panel);
scroll.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 300);
parent.add(scroll);
```

all parent layouts is set to null except for this one because it must use layout manager right? and the crazy thing is when i code this in a simple program it works but if i try to add this in my actual program everthing is ok except for the panel that i insert on its constructor only the border, the background of JScrollBar appears and also i notice that if i just add the panel directly to the parent component even i set the layout to GridLayout it still act that it is set to null.. Please can someone help me.

Comment: It's hard to determine any particular problems when you don't post an [mre].  The parent JPanel of the JScrollPane has to have a Swing layout manager.  All JPanels should have a Swing layout manager.

Comment: *all parent layouts is set to null* - why? Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. *when i code this in a simple program it works but if i try to add this in my actual program...*. And that is the problem. As the code gets more complex the layout becomes more complex and one of your null layouts is causing a problem.  Learn to use Swing the way it was designed and avoid potential issues.

Answer (score 0):

problem fixed..

```
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
pane.revalidate();
pane.repaint();
```